# Why standalone deriving fails with rigid type on a record with existential quantification?

Tags: haskell, types, ghc, existential-type

I am trying to compare associated types with existential ones, and wrote following snippet:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}

import Prelude 

data App = forall t. Eq t => App { f :: t }

deriving instance Eq App
```

Type checks barks with:

> Couldn't match expected type ‘b’ with actual type ‘b1’   ‘b1’ is a
> rigid type variable bound by

At first glance the same snippet is provided as a solution on [stack overflow earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46038338/342882).

I found probably related GHC [issue](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/21514), but disabling PolyKinds extension doesn't have any effect and Polysemy plugin either.

GHC 9.2.5 is used.

P.S.

So in practice both approaches don't support deriving.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't a GHC bug: there just isn't a sensible definition of `(==) :: App -> App -> Bool` in the first place.

Given `a :: App` and `b :: App`, we know they must be (disregarding bottoms) `a = App x` for some `x` (of some type `X` with `Eq X`) and `b = App y` for some `y` (of some type `Y` with `Eq Y`). But because you defined `App` existentially, there's absolutely no reason for `x` and `y` to be comparable, since they have different types. *Within* each type `X` and `Y`, you could use the `Eq` methods. So `x == x` makes sense, and so does `y == y`, but `x == y` doesn't make sense, since you'd be using `(==)` at the type `X -> Y -> Bool`. Therefore the tentative definition

```
instance Eq App where App x == App y = x == y
```

is considered nonsense, regardless of whether it's generated by `deriving` or written by hand. The type error you are getting is, at it's heart, just "you are trying to use `(==)` on objects of potentially different types."

Or, in short, exactly how is the expression `App (5 :: Int) == App ("5" :: String)` supposed to evaluate?

Perhaps you would like it if objects of different types always compared disequal. Then you need to store type information in `App` using `Typeable` or `TypeRep`. You compare for type equality first, and only upon getting a yes can you compare the values.

```
import Data.Typeable
data App = forall t. (Typeable t, Eq t) => App t
instance Eq App where
  App x == App y = case cast y of -- try to cast y to type of x (type information flows from (1))
    Just y' -> x == y' -- (1) x and y' are (==)'d, so they must be of the same type
    Nothing -> False
```

Comment: thanks, IMHO it should a flag / another deriving strategy to avoid manually typing Eq instance with dozens of regular fields and 1 existential.

Comment: @DaniilIaitskov if your real concern is about a record with many fields, only one of which is existentially typed, then you should ask a new question about that.